# Extract String from column SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column that has a string in a format such as {"en_US":"Hadayek Helwan","ar_EG":"حدائق حلوان"}

I would like to extract both the English phrase "Hadayek Helwan" in one column and Arabic phrase "حدائق حلوان" in another column.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is really stored as this more or less json string, you can parse it like so:

```
select
new json(<your column>).<json entity>
from
...
```

So to get the english one, you would use
`new json(<your column>).en_US`

The entity name is case sensitive.  This will only work if the entity exists once in the string.